# Define the default int to unsigned int

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, int, unsigned

How can I (***if I can***) set the default int variable (in a specific program) to be unsigned int?

I mean that if `int` is written in the program, the compiler treats it like `unsigned int`.

My compiler is gcc 4.6.2

EDIT: I am not authorized to touch the code.

Comment: Not sure if that's a good idea... But maybe a macro?

Comment: You should really not do that.

Comment: This seems like an extraordinarily bad idea.

Comment: Is this because of laziness? Because, you know, you could just use a simple `typedef unsigned int uint;` to save you some typing.

Comment: @yoni: Why do you want to do that? Maybe we can help better if you tell us exactly what you want to achieve (because there may be a better way than to redefine `int`, which is bound to cause problems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the default signedness of `int` because it is by definition a signed type (§6.2.5/4). Consider the `main` function which must return type `int` (§5.1.2.2.1/1), if you change the default signedness somehow, then `main` will return `unsigned int`, and this will cause undefined behaviour, rendering your entire application relatively useless.

You can't create a macro, because if `int` expands to `unsigned int`, then if you have declared `unsigned int` somewhere, you will end up with `unsigned unsigned int`, which is not a valid type.

Comment: Oops, sorry, question is tagged C++ but I have quoted clauses from the C specification, but I am more-or-less adamant that the same restrictions apply in C++ as well.

Comment: thank you, now I understand the problem. Why it was so hard to some people to answer this (or like this) simple answer. Why to answer super-evil answers? why?

Answer (score 3):

A super-evil

```
#define int unsigned int
```

could work, but is definitely not Standard compliant and you might need to make your compiler be less strict (which is a bad thing).

Other things you can do is find and replace all occurrences of `int` (without a preceding `unsigned`) and replace those with `my_typedefed_int` and add a

```
typedef unsigned int my_typedefed_int
```

Which is Standard compliant but is more involved and might not be possible.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the second suggestion? He could as well replace all occurences of `int` by `unsigned int` then.

Comment: Niklas: it would allow other types to be used/tested in a simple and transparent way.

Comment: @Niklas Baumstark: With second suggestion, once op realizes that using unsigned int for everything was a bad idea, he will be able to switch type (to int) globally by modifying one line of code - instead of using massive search/replace for entire project.

Comment: The first suggestion should probably not be suggested. I doubt that it is legal to redefine in a preprocessor macro a keyword of the language, but even if that was possible the problem is that it would be *very* prone to errors, if some translation units are compiled with/without that macro defined you would have different semantics in the code, inconsistent declaration/definitions of functions or even ODR violations (consider inlined functions)

Comment: @David: hence the `super-evil`.